# How to eliminate the loop and using numpy reshape?

Tags: numpy, reshape

I have the following code,

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im

B = 9
pic = np.array(im.open('portrait.png'))
pic = pic[pic.shape[0] % B:, pic.shape[1] % B:, :3]
reduced, _i, _j = [], 0, 0
for i in range(B, pic.shape[0] + B, B):
    for j in range(B, pic.shape[1] + B, B):
        pix = pic[_i:i, _j:j].reshape(B * B, 3).mean(axis=0)
        reduced.append(pix.astype(np.uint8))
        _j = j
    _i, _j = i, 0
reduced = np.array(reduced)
reduced = reduced.reshape((pic.shape[0] // B, pic.shape[1] // B, 3))
plt.title(reduced.shape)
plt.imshow(reduced)
plt.show()
```

It essentially iterates over `B` by `B` blocks of the image and turns them into one pixel by taking their mean.

So this,

[image: Van Gogh]

Becomes this,

[image]

I think this could be done somehow by reshaping, taking the mean along some axis and then reshaping again. But I am not sure how to take out that loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce `BxB` blocks within the image as extra axes, then take the mean along those axes:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im

B = 9
pic = np.array(im.open('portrait.png'))

h, w, c = pic.shape
H, W = h - h % B, w - w % B

reduced = (
    pic[-H:,-W:]                             # crop to multiple of block size
        .reshape((H // B, B, W // B, B, c))  # split y and x axes into blocks
        .mean(axis=(1,3))                    # take the mean
        .astype(np.uint8)                    # convert from float
)

plt.title(reduced.shape)
plt.imshow(reduced)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does `.clip(0, 255)` do here?

Comment: Ha, honestly it's force of habit when converting from float to uint8, I'll remove it. You're not going to have mean values outside the uint8 range so it's not going to have an effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using an extra library, you can achieve it with [`einops`](https://einops.rocks/) in a straight forward and self explanatory manner, as follows:

```py
import einops

img = ...
B=9

im_reduced = einops.reduce(img, "(h Bh) (w Bw) C -> h w C", "mean", Bh=B, Bw=B)
```